# A comment that has changed author

Tags: bug, status-completed

In my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10085/why-is-aleph-0-the-smallest-infty/10088#10088), I am pretty sure that the comment "@Arturo, I use AC without any guilt!" was written by *me*, yet now I see it incorporated into Robin's comment that immediately preceded it.

That's surely a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, what Isaac said. My mistake. I deleted that section, so if you would like to add it again as a properly attributed comment, feel free to do so.

Answer (score 12):

I'm guessing that's not a bug *per se*, but human error from [when Jeff said/did](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/threatening-emails-from-jeff-atwood/1291#1291):

> I'm going through and manually merging all the Robin Chapman comments on math.se, I want to record some of the comments responding to his comments as I do so (I delete these afterwards, since after the comments are merged, it's no longer relevant.)